# Exchanging file between routes

Tags: apache-camel

I trying to unzip a file and separately process xml files with a specific Xpath value. Below is the Spring DSL.

```xml
<camel:route id="unzip-file" startupOrder="400">
    <from uri="file:{{download.folder}}?move={{download.archive}}&amp;consumer.delay=10000"/>
    <unmarshal ref="zipFileDataFormat"/>
    <split streaming="true">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
        <to uri="log:org.apache.camel?level=INFO&amp;showAll=true&amp;multiline=true"/>
        <to uri="file:{{extract.folder}}"/>
    </split>
</camel:route>

<camel:route id="process-extracted-files" startupOrder="300">
    <from uri="file://{{extract.folder}}?noop=true&amp;consumer.delay=10000&amp;delete=false"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${file:ext} regex '(?i)(xml)'</simple>
            <to uri="direct:process-xml-file"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log message="ignoring file ${file:name}, not XML"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</camel:route>

<camel:route id="process-xml-file" startupOrder="200">
    <from uri="direct:process-extracted-files"/>
    <log message="processing file ${file:name}" />
    <choice>
        <when>
            <xpath>/invoices/@region='region1'</xpath>
            <split>
                <xpath>/invoices/invoice</xpath>
                <log message="${body}"/>
            </split>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log message="ignoring file ${file:name}, not 'region1'"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</camel:route>
```

I'm getting the error below in the logs, any idea what i'm missing.

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[process-extracted-] [process-extracted-] [file://C:/Temp/invoices/extract?consumer.delay=10000&delete=false&noop=true       ] [       353]
[process-extracted-] [choice1           ] [when[simple{${file:ext} regex '(?i)(xml)'}]choice[]                           ] [       354]
[process-extracted-] [to6               ] [direct:process-xml-file                                                       ] [         5]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-crm.bigcorp.co.za-51788-1385461098541-0-4
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-crm.bigcorp.co.za-51788-1385461098541-0-3, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Temp\invoices\extract\INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl, CamelFileLastModified=1385450517644, CamelFileLength=205502, CamelFileName=INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl, CamelFileNameConsumed=INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl, CamelFileNameOnly=INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl, CamelFileParent=C:\Temp\invoices\extract, CamelFilePath=C:\Temp\invoices\extract\INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl, CamelFileRelativePath=INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
    BodyType            org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile
    Body                [Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\Temp\invoices\extract\INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl]]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://process-xml-file]. Exchange[INVOICES_V2_DAILY_DELTA_20131105.xMl]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change URI of the child route definition to **direct:process-xml-file** (same as invocation)

```
<from uri="direct:process-xml-file"/>
```

Comment: Arrrrrgggghhhh, screams and pulls hair then goes back to work.